# UICollectionView - Remove All Items Or Update to Refresh it

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am working on an UICollectionView based app, and I load it by -

```
    NSUInteger newNumCells = [self.imageArray count];
    NSIndexPath* newIndexPath;

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [indexPaths removeAllObjects];

    for (int i = 0; i < newNumCells; ++i) {
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:newIndexPath];
    }

    self.indexPaths = indexPaths;
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

It's working well.

Then I have another search function at same page, so when I get new search result from server, the self.imageArray content changed, I want to refresh current `UICollectionView,` for example, remove all items, and insert new items from current self.imageArray, but when I do delete items, always crash -

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            //self.indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
            //[self.imageArray removeAllObjects];

            self.indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
            [self.imageArray removeAllObjects];
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:self.indexPaths];
            [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

            //[self.collectionView reloadData];

            //[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];

        } completion:nil];
```

Crash info -

```
Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionViewData.m:341
2014-03-07 11:47:48.450 pixcell8[9089:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xb4a8430> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

So I want to ask how to do refresh the `UICollectionView` with new data? Thanks.

Update : this bug is because I have used a custom layout, and it had some wrong logics, and now it's fixed.

Comment: I somehow encounter a similar problem that produces the same error (receiving layout attributes for a non-existing index path). I'm also using a custom layout object which I believe the error came from. Could you describe what went wrong in your case?

Comment: @jchnxu:  hmm it's long time, basically I tried an example from github.com, and the bug is at - (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect and - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath, it didn't call [self prepareLayout] correctly, but I can't find the example anymore, hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loading a collection view is very similar to a table view. Use the delegate and dataSource protocols for handling most of this.

for you case something like

```
 self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

then in dataSource methods

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return self.imageArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Set up and return your cell
}
```

When you want to change content you can replace or update contents of imageArray and reloadData.

New content from API comes in

```
[self.imageArray removeAllObjects];
[self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:apiResponseArray];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

There are other approaches that maybe a bit more efficient but this should get you started. You can use the other methods for insert and batch as needed once the basic set up is done correctly.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xa474420> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'

Comment: The first time, API will return 20 objects, and the second time it will return 1 object.

Comment: did you remove the insertItemsAtIndexPaths: code you had (shown in original post)? And the batch update code?

Comment: Your code is valid, actually the bug is from my custom layout class. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom I'm still facing the issue as you faced.. I'm working on the same scenario, could you please tell me how to resolve this issue. it swallows 2 nights :(

Comment: Add [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout] after reload step.